# Expected Value in Urn Problem

Tags: probability

I just learned about Random Variables and Expected values and i tried solving the following question from my textbook

In an urn are N white balls. The balls are arbitrarily taken and at the same time a similar red ball is placed in the urn. So the number of balls in the urn has not changed. The same process is repeated until all N balls in the urn are red. Let X be the number of withdrawals made. Calculate the expected value of X

I'm having real struggles to Modell this problem correctly,  i tried via diffrent distribution concepts but non of them worked. Could someone give me some details on how to structure this problem

Comment: This is the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  Can you see that?

Comment: If there are R red balls and W white balls, what is the expected number of draws until you draw a white ball?

Comment: no i don't quite see it, because every time we draw a white ball our probabillity for the next white ball changes and in the article it is said that the probability is equaly likley.